# Convert NSString to NSNumber gives different value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber, valueconverter

I am trying to convert a `NSString` to a `NSNumber`, but I am getting a different value from what I expect.

```
for(ClassA *item in appD.classArray)
{
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; // Method A
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    item.number = [f numberFromString:stringA];

    item.number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:stringA]; // Method B

    item.number = @([stringA intValue]); // Method C

    item.number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[stringA integerValue]]; // Method D
    NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
    NSLog(@"item.number %@",item.number);
    [ClassA updateClassInfo:item];
}
```

#### Output on console is:

```
string A 111775
item.number -19297
```

Using different method produce same result. The converted string will change to negative.

#### Edit

P/S: my string A in my app is increasing with value everytime I run it.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber new];
NSLog(@"stringA %@",stringA);

item.number = [NSNumber new];

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
number = [f numberFromString:stringA];
NSLog(@"number %@",number);
item.number = number;
NSLog(@"item.number %@",item.number);

number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:stringA];
NSLog(@"number %@",number);
item.number = number;
NSLog(@"item.number %@",item.number);

number = @([stringA intValue]);
NSLog(@"number %@",number);
item.number = number;
NSLog(@"item.number %@",item.number);

number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[stringA integerValue]];
NSLog(@"number %@",number);
item.number = number;
NSLog(@"item.number %@",item.number);
```

#### Output on console is:

```
2014-06-11 18:06:31.262 App[751:907] stringA 111796
2014-06-11 18:06:31.266 App[751:907] number 111796
2014-06-11 18:06:31.269 App[751:907] item.number -19276
2014-06-11 18:06:31.271 App[751:907] number 111796
2014-06-11 18:06:31.274 App[751:907] item.number -19276
2014-06-11 18:06:31.276 App[751:907] number 111796
2014-06-11 18:06:31.278 App[751:907] item.number -19276
2014-06-11 18:06:31.280 App[751:907] number 111796
2014-06-11 18:06:31.287 App[751:907] item.number -19276
```

Comment: What is your question?  When I run this code I get an `NSNumber` (or `NSDecimalNumber` in the case of method B) with the value 111775 returned by all four of your methods (on both OS X and iOS).

Comment: I am trying to convert the string to number but it is giving me the negative value. not sure why.

Comment: Because you're using `%d` rather than `%@` to format the NSNumber and what you're seeing is a pointer value?

Comment: %d???? Which indicate is %d?

Comment: I have used your code and I am getting expected output :              2014-06-11 11:11:32.192 SampleApp[5404:70b] string A 111775
2014-06-11 11:11:32.194 SampleApp[5404:70b] converted string 111775

Comment: does it have to do with the for loop?

Comment: Whats the data type of the ivar number in your class "ClassA"?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your `item.number` property is a managed attribute, in a Core Data managed object.

Note that every Core Data attribute has a type:

[image: Core Data Attribute Type]

For example, if your attribute type is `Integer 16`, your property setter will wrap the number to 16 bits. I guess that's what is happening here.

Solution: set your attribute type to be big enough to save your values, e.g. `Integer32`.

Comment: Thanks it worked after changed to Integer32.. Sorry cause a fuzz to everyone.. Im a beginner in ios development..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `item.number` property is a `NSNumber`?

#### This code works:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

            NSString *stringA = @"111775";
            NSNumber *number;

            NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; // Method A
            [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            number = [f numberFromString:stringA];
            NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
            NSLog(@"number %@", number);

            number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:stringA]; // Method B
            NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
            NSLog(@"number %@", number);

            number = @([stringA intValue]); // Method C
            NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
            NSLog(@"number %@", number);

            number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[stringA integerValue]]; // Method D CHANGED, because unsigned int is not equal to integer
            NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
            NSLog(@"number %@", number);
    }
}
```

#### Ouput:

> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.587 Untitled[573:507] string A 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.588 Untitled[573:507] number 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.588 Untitled[573:507] string A 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.588 Untitled[573:507] number 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.589 Untitled[573:507] string A 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.589 Untitled[573:507] number 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.590 Untitled[573:507] string A 111775
>
> 2014-06-11 10:33:48.590 Untitled[573:507] number 111775

---

As you wished, the same test with a class and a property **with the same correct output**:

#### class .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassWithNumber : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *item;

@end
```

#### class .m

```
#import "ClassWithNumber.h"

@implementation ClassWithNumber

@end
```

#### main

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassWithNumber.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *stringA = @"111775";
        ClassWithNumber *numberClass = [ClassWithNumber new];

        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; // Method A
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        numberClass.item = [f numberFromString:stringA];
        NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
        NSLog(@"number %@", numberClass.item);

        numberClass.item = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:stringA]; // Method B
        NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
        NSLog(@"number %@", numberClass.item);

        numberClass.item = @([stringA intValue]); // Method C
        NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
        NSLog(@"number %@", numberClass.item);

        numberClass.item = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[stringA integerValue]]; // Method D
        NSLog(@"string A %@",stringA);
        NSLog(@"number %@", numberClass.item);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my number is of type
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;
in my database

Comment: Ok to make it clear I put output everywhere, every one of the ways work the same & correct.

Comment: Changed method D, it worked for the example but is not correct.

Comment: With a property nothing changes, when it is correctly set. Sorry did the naming not like you.

Comment: the converted value is correct but saving it gives a different value

Comment: What do you mean by *saving*? The property of your class is updated. If you save it in `[ClassA updateClassInfo:item];
`, then there must be the error.

Comment: sry my word usage wrong. should be assign instead of save

Comment: Look at my code with the class it works. Value is correct after assignment, numberClass.item is not negative